# An optimization problem involving orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ be an **orthogonal matrix**. Then $\mathrm{vec}X\in\mathbb{R}^9$ is a 9 by 1 vector formed by stacking the columns of the matrix $X$ on top of one another. Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{9\times 9}$, find the optimal orthogonal matrix $X$ minimizing the following objective function.
$$J=\left(\mathrm{vec}X\right)^T A \mathrm{vec}X$$
I think Kronecker product may be useful for solving this problem. Does a closed-form solution exist? If not, is it possible to solve it iteratively? Thanks.

**EDIT**：

a) Here $A$ doesn't have any special property. But it is also acceptable if solutions can be obtained by adding some properties on $A$.

b) In the original problem, $X$ is constrained as a *rotation* matrix. But I think that would be even harder, so I put $X$ as an orthogonal matrix herein. Of course, optimal rotation matrices are better.

Comment: Does $A$ has any property, e.g. being positive definite?

Comment: Note sure whether there is a closed form solution. But you could solve it iteratively (e.g. using the Newton method or Gradient Descent) and the Lie algebra so3. Is X a proper rotation $\det(X)=1$ or can it also be a reflection?

Comment: @Hauke Strasdat: Yes, but the general Newton or Gradient methods suffer from several drawbacks: (1) convergence is not guaranteed. (2) Orthogonality is not satisfied. (3) initial values are required and may converge to local but not global minima. I think better solutions should be possible due to the specific format of the objective function.

Comment: You can preserve orthogonality, if you do the update in the tangent space (Lie algerba). Thus, you calculate the gradient: $\nabla J =\frac{\partial }{\partial \epsilon}  \text{vec} (\exp(\epsilon)X)^\top A \text{vec} (\exp(\epsilon)X)|_{\epsilon=0}$ with $\exp(\cdot)$ being the Rodriguez formula. Now you can iteratively update $X$ using gradient descent: $X' = \exp(-\alpha\nabla J) X$.

Comment: On the issue of rotations vs. reflections, note since X is of odd dimension and can be replaced wlog in the objective function by -X if necessary, there is no problem restricting attention to det(X)=1.

Comment: @Hardmath: I see now that if $X$ is the minimum then $-X$ is a minimum too. Is this what you were saying?

Comment: @Hauke Strasdat: Right, and that if X is 3x3 orthogonal, exactly one of X and -X is properly a rotation (as Shiyu original wants).

Comment: @Hauke Strasdat: the $\epsilon$ in the Rodriguez formula is a skew-symmetric matrix, right? Is it possible to find a good step size $\alpha$ and prove the convergence? BTW, can you also give some reference on this method? I think it is interesting.

Comment: @hardmath, you and Shiyu are both correct about my solution. For some reason, I though it could be moved like a matrix.

Comment: @Shiyu: I am happy to provide some more details in a bit. Just wondering how your problem is motivated. Is there any particular application you try to solve?

Comment: Following the footsteps of @HaukeStrasdat , the space of 3x3 rotation matrices [can be parameterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle) in terms of an axis (unit vector) and an angle of rotation about that axis, a fact [proven by Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_rotation_theorem).  In principle for given $A$ we can maximize with respect to the angle of rotation symbolically, leaving just a 2D optimization problem over the 2-sphere for the axis of rotation.  While daunting in full generality, the case $A$ diagonal seems tractable.

Comment: @Hauke Strasdat: Frankly, this problem comes from a 3D computer vision problem. More precisely, it is a pose estimation problem. I read the paper "2000 - TPAMI - Fast and globally convergent pose estimation from video images", and find an interesting objective function there. I reformulated that objective function to this one, and try to see if I can find the closed-form solution. I notice you are also a student in computer vision. So I believe you may familiar with pose estimation, which is a very old problem.

Comment: @hardmath: Interesting! I believe gradient descent with orthogonality constraints may have been investigated by other people.

Comment: You might try asking this on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit late, but I believe this might help.

Use the Cayley parametrization of orthogonal matrices. Example usage in optimization: [A Feasible Method for Optimization with Orthogonality Constraints](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/102167/TR10-26.PDF?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

[WayBack link](http://web.archive.org/web/20180516132510/http://www.caam.rice.edu/%7Ewy1/paperfiles/Rice_CAAM_TR10-26_OptManifold.PDF) of "A Feasible Method for Optimization with Orthogonality Constraints"

You might want to start by just understanding the Wiki article on the [Cayley transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform) and why a parametrization helps (you can do the optimization without constraints, which should be easier)

Comment: Please explain how this "might help".  A link-only Answer risks becoming obsolete as links break, and it is advantageous to the Reader to have a clear expectation of what they would find if the link were followed.

Comment: @Patrick:  The old "example usage" link was successfully crawled by the Wayback Machine in May of 2018.  Here's a link [at UCLA.edu](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/papers/feasible_method_matrix_manifold.html) associated with the second named author, so presumably of potential longevity.  Of course an elaborate self-contained explanation would be welcome here.

Comment: @hardmath : This link "Here's a link at UCLA.edu associated with the second named author" is also broken :-(

Comment: +1 Your advice to transform the problem from constrained $\to$ unconstrained is spot-on. Too many students reflexively reach for textbook methods without considering the alternatives.

Comment: @AndrásAszódi , here's the fixed link of hardmath's URL: http://web.archive.org/web/20180806162535/https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/papers/feasible_method_matrix_manifold.html